# nodejs pm2 --merge-logs with -l option

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am using pm2 to deploy nodejs application.
Here is my syntax

```
NODE_ENV=production pm2 start server.js --name "demoapp" --merge-logs -l "/var/log/demoapp/demo-application.log"
```

But it is not able to start the application. If I remove the --merge-logs option application starts and logs are generated with suffix(PID).

I want logs to be generated without suffix.

Comment: Is `/var/log/demoapp/demo-application.log` writable for the UID you're starting `pm2` as?

Comment: @robertklep Yes it is writable, as I mentioned without the --merge-logs parameter it is able to write to the log file but with a suffix.

Comment: _"but with a suffix"_, so it writes to a _different_ file in that case, doesn't it?

Comment: @robertklep Yes, do I need to create the exact file before hand and give permission and then run pm2?

Comment: Try this (as the user that will also be running `pm2`): `touch /var/log/demoapp/demo-application.log`

Comment: @robertklep Thanks, buddy ! The problem is solved.